# Documents in Composite Template error in tabs

Tags: c#, templates, docusignapi, document

I add 2 composite templates to the envelope,
one of the composites has 2 recipients and 1 document,
the other composite has 1 recipient and 1 document,
however the signature tabs are only shown in the first document.
as shown in the image, the signature tabs are only on the first document
[enter image description here][1]

The Json:

```
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
       "document": {
        "documentBase64": "xxxx",
        "name:": "xxxx",
        "documentId":"xxx"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                "email": "joao@protonmail.com",
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                "name": "joao da Silva",
                "recipientId": "8c5fcdce-fe94-4379-8df7-608e753db718",
                "requireIdLookup": "true",
                "roleName": "Assinante",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "smsAuthentication": {
                  "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                    "+5546994528888"
                  ]
                },
                "status": "Created",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "documentId": "1878974182",
                      "recipientId": "8c5fcdce-fe94-4379-8df7-608e753db718"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                "email": "joana@gmail.com",
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                "name": "Joana Silva",
                "recipientId": "11f6f9fc-c622-4d9b-9a98-4401a59cefbe",
                "requireIdLookup": "true",
                "roleName": "Testemunha",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "smsAuthentication": {
                  "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                    "+5546994528888"
                  ]
                },
                "status": "Created",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "documentId": "1878974182",
                      "recipientId": "11f6f9fc-c622-4d9b-9a98-4401a59cefbe"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "9b13a1dc-456c-4dff-87d8-ae4205dfb4eb"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     "document": {
            "documentBase64": "xxxx",
            "name:": "xxxx",
            "documentId":"xxx"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "deliveryMethod": "Email",
                "email": "pedro@outlook.com",
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                "name": "Pedro Silva",
                "recipientId": "edd53f74-3e87-4380-859a-6d1fee7c5c92",
                "requireIdLookup": "true",
                "roleName": "Assinante",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "smsAuthentication": {
                  "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                    "+5546994528888"
                  ]
                },
                "status": "Created",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "documentId": "1238654318",
                      "recipientId": "edd53f74-3e87-4380-859a-6d1fee7c5c92"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "3"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "2",
          "templateId": "33b13eb1-25d5-46ee-b322-af433665b369"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}``


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxbX3.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **SignHereTab** elements you specified won't show because they are missing something to determine their location. You can either use X/Y coordinates, or you can use anchor strings, but without any information, DocuSign won't know where to place them.

The tags you do see on the first document probably come from the template itself. Note if you meant for all tags to come from the template itself then you have to check the **roleName** and make sure it matches the role you defined in the template (For which you placed tags for).

Comment: Yes the roleName match. Tabs are set on the templates. Shouldn't documents take these tabs from the templates

Comment: You have 3 templatesIDs, so you are sure you're not confusing one of the templates? you only mentions 2 templates in your question, what is the third one? where are the roles?

Comment: has 2 composite templates, with two template ids, one in each serverTemplate. Everything is apparently set correctly.

Comment: Can you try one template at a time and see if it works ok ?

Comment: yes, with one template and one document, works. It seems that the tabs are all over the first document, that the second template is not applied to the second document

Comment: templates are not "applied" to documents. I think there's some confusion. You have the same document in each template? Is there conflict between these templates?

Comment: no, it's a template with two subscribers, for a Document1. Another template with 1 subscriber, for another Document2

Comment: but if you use this second template separately it also works ok?

Comment: good question, i will try. The first yes works, but the second i have to try

Comment: Template are not applied to documents? https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetemplates/applytodocument/

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, are you using this endpoint that you just linked?